# select certain number of immediate siblings w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple divs like this:

```
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>

<div class="large"></div>
<div class="large"></div>

<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
<div class="small"></div>
```

I want to select every 4 .small divs to wrap in another div so it's like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
    <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the first example, there can be more than 4 adjacent ones, but I still want to group every 4 .small divs.

Any idea would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to allow for other elements like your "large" ones potentially being in between such that a group of 4 "small" ones might overlap the "large"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I've done it in the past.

```
var smallDivs = $('div.small'),
    chunkLength = 4;

for (var i = 0, length = smallDivs.length; i < length; i += chunkLength) {
    smallDivs.slice(i, i + chunkLength).wrapAll('<div class="box" />');
}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eAuQN/).

I *chunk* the selected elements into chunks of a desired length and then call `wrapAll()` on the sub-selection.

Just for the hell of it, here is how you'd do it without jQuery...

```
var smallDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div.small'),
    chunkLength = 4,
    box;

for (var i = 0, length = smallDivs.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (!(i % chunkLength)) {
        box = document.createElement('div');
        box.className = 'box';
        smallDivs[i].parentNode.appendChild(box);
    }

    box.appendChild(smallDivs[i]);

}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8Z3y/).

Of course, for old browsers that don't support `document.querySelectorAll()` or `document.getElementsByClassName()`, replace the element selecting code with...

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    smallDivs = [];

for (var i = 0, length = divs.length; i < length; i++) {
    if ((' ' + divs[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' small ') >= 0) {
        smallDivs.push(divs[i]);
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKbr3/).

Answer (score 0):

You use `slice` or `gt()` and `lt()`
See example below

```
$(".small").slice(4,10).wrapAll('<div class"smallWrapper"></div>');
```

Or

```
$(".small:gt(5):lt(10)").wrapAll('<div class"smallWrapper">
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5jsf/)